# What does "core language" mean?

Tags: c++, gcc

In the table on [this page](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/cxx0x_status.html) from the GCC documentation, one of the items (about halfway down the table) is listed as "core language" only. What does that mean? What parts of the language wouldn't be included?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Standard library is part of the language. To express the subset of the language that concerns only with the rules of the syntax, semantic rules, and such but not with the library, people use the term *core language*. For example there is a working group called "core working group" (CWG) and "library working group" (LWG) in the C++ committee.

Answer (score 3):

People often mean everything of C++ except the standard library, which is also part of the language specification.

As an more authoritative example Stephan T. Lavavej (STL) is a key C++ developer at Microsoft. In his lecture series about the *Core Language* he defines it to be **anything you have access to without including any header.**

He does not consider himself a Core Language developer. For example he worked on `shared_ptr` which is a fundamental part of C++11, arguably more fundamental than the strings and streams the comments mention.

The C++ standard does not mention *Core Language*, but the *standard library* is

```
17 Library introduction
18 Language support library
19 Diagnostics library
20 General utilities library
21 Strings library
22 Localization library
23 Containers library
24 Iterators library
25 Algorithms library
26 Numerics library
27 Input/output library
28 Regular expressions library
29 Atomic operations library
30 Thread support library
```

I would argue chapter 1-16 is (almost?) only concerned with the core language, but there may be more.

Comment: Everything except the STL would include streams and strings. :)

Comment: Clause 17 is also part of the library, and I would dispute that most people in the committee call it the Standard Template Library, they call it the Standard Library

Comment: Yes, 17 is an introduction. Read again, I did not claim that they call the standard library the STL.

Comment: There's a small set of things that are intermediate between core and library; they're the ones in 18, Language Support Library. Things like `operator new`, `operator delete`, and `type_info`, which require close cooperation between the compiler and the library.

Comment: @PeteBecker, Operator new is explicitly called standard library in the standard but I guess few talk and think of it like that.

Comment: @JohanLundberg - yes, my point was that there are **some things** in the standard library that have an intimate connection with the core language. `operator new` is one: the compiler calls it even though there's no call to it in the source code and even if you haven't #included the appropriate header.

Answer (score 1):

Johannes's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13221794/981959) explains what "core language" means in general.  In the specific context you ask about it means that the core language parts of [n3050](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3050.html) are implemented in GCC 4.7, but not necessarily the library parts (those changes from the paper that apply to Clauses 17-30)

In fact some of the library changes are also implemented in GCC 4.7, but the library status is documented [elsewhere](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/libstdc++/manual/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011)

Answer (score -2):

core language means it include basic concept which include syntax and other rule related to it.