# Difference between library feature and core language feature

Tags: c++

I have heard about the term core language feature and library feature but i can not understand the term correctly.I have read an answer in stack overflow that std::initializer_list is not only only library-feature. It is a core-langugage feature as well.I cant understand it.

Comment: I think that anything in the std namespace is a core feature and anything that has a different namespace is a library feature (e.g std::cout vs libraryName::function)

Comment: I think the phrase *anything you have access to without including any header.* unambiguously defines what the core language is. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13221807/434551) to the question that @Barmar linked to.

Comment: @GabrieleB-David No. Anything you have access to without an `#include` is a language feature.

Comment: @EJP So printing to the standard output is not a core language feature of c++ (or c, for that matter)?